# Finding displacement of a body in freefall for an unknown time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, free-fall

A brick is dropped from a building. After some time, the brick falls 40 meters in one second. Find how far the brick travels in the next second.

My intuition for this problem is to use two kinematics equations $$v_y^2 =v_{0y}^2+2a_y(y-y_0) \hspace{.5cm}\text{and}\hspace{.5cm} y-y_0=\frac{v_{0y}+v_y}{2}t$$ where $y-y_0=40$, $a_y=9.8$ and $t=1$. Writing $v_{0y}$ in terms of $v_y$ in the second equation gives me $v_{0y}=80-v_y$.  Plugging this into the first equation gives us $v_y^2=(80-v_y)^2+2(9.8)(40)$ where we can solve $v_y$ as $v_y=44.9$. This is the velocity after the 1 second where it falls 40 meters. Finally, plugging this into the position equation $$y-y_0=v_{y}t+\frac{1}{2}a_yt^2 $$ as $v_{0y}$ and solving for the position in the next second gives us $$y-y_0=44.9(1)+\frac{1}{2}(9.8)(1)^2 $$ or $49.8$ meters.

Was my process correct for solving this problem?

Comment: In general, "check-my-work" questions are off-topic on this board, so I'm afraid this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: I see questions here that are closed because users don't make an attempt. I showed my understanding, but I don't know if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your approach is correct. 
But you must have solved a quadratic equation for this. This might be a little time consuming.

Instead you can use the equation for distance covered in $ n^{th} $ second. It is given by-

$S_n = u_0 + \frac {1}{2}a (2n-1)$

Here the case is even easier as $u_0$ is zero. You will get the $n^{th}$ time at which displacement is 40m. Once you get the time you can easily calculate the velocity and thereafter the distance travelled after that 1 second by the equations of motion.

$v_y = v_0 + a_yt$
$y - y_0 = v_0yt + \frac{1}{2}a_yt^2$

This will save your lot of time.

*In case you don't know equation for the distance travelled in $n^{th}$ second you can easily derive it from the equations of motion. *

Comment: The squared term of $v_y$ actually cancels so no quadratic solving is necessary.

Comment: Oh... Nice. ..Now you got one more method to work on. .